# Arduino 2D array too large (TFT touch lcd)

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I'm currently using a TFTv2 Seeedstudio Shield with an Arduino Mega 2560. I was making it draw things on the screen when I realized there was no method to get the color of a pixel. My immediate thought was to go into the library files and add a method that would return the color (one integer) that corresponds to the pixel at `(x, y)`. The number of pixels on the screen is 240 * 320 = 76800. When I make an array that has an index of 76800, the sketch compiles just fine:

```
INT16U pixels[76800];
```

but:

```
INT16U pixels[320][240];
```

is a no-no.

I get an error saying that the array size is too big.

The only other things I changed in the TFTv2.cpp file are the `setPixel(int x, int y, int color)` method and I added a method called `getColorAt(int x, int y)` which returned an `unsigned int8`. I also added the method in the TFTv2.h header file. Here are these changes:

Header file:

```
INT16U getColorAt(INT8U poX, INT8U poY);
```

CPP file:

```
void TFT::setPixel(INT16U poX, INT16U poY,INT16U color)
{
    setXY(poX, poY);
    pixels[poX][poY] = color; //added this line myself
    sendData(color);
}

INT8U TFT::getColorAt(INT8U poX, INT8U poY)
{
    return pixels[poX][poY];
}
```

What is the difference here? I thought a two-dimensional array would hold the same amount of data that a single array with the same number of indices would.

Any input is appreciated, and if you need any other information, please do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem, but you've got your sizes all mixed up. The method `TFT::getColorAt` is using 8-bits for X, Y, and the return value. But `setPixel` uses 16-bits for all. And the header file conflicts with the CPP file.

Comment: That probably would cause some some issues. I fixed it so that all of them agreed on INT16U, but I still am getting the same "size of array 'pixels' is to large" error.

Comment: I would expect that a common implementation of 2 dimensional arrays is an array of x pointers to arrays of length y. The pointers would take up extra memory.

Comment: I looked through WG21 a bit. It seems like the 8.3.5 actually does mandate a contiguous memory layout for arrays, which would mean the size shouldn't change in this code.

Comment: I just noticed that this is tagged C as well. Is it C or C++?

Comment: You don't have enough RAM for a frame buffer; don't attempt to create one.

Comment: The key fact for this is from the datasheet `8KB SRAM` you cant create a buffer that big when you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: If I don't have enough RAM, why does it let me create the one dimensional with the same number of indices?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's C++, but I'm not experienced enough to tell the difference just by looking at it yet.